# Netlify and ngrok linking

Tags: ngrok, server-side-rendering, netlify

I have a front-end deployed on **Netlify** and a back-end is deployed on localhost which is exposed using **ngrok**.

Is it possible to link them so that when I click on the **Netlify** link, it would send request to my localhost server exposed from **ngrok** ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us some code you have trouble with and ask a specific question about that. Finding a library or suggesting something like that is Offtopic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: The short answer is yes **IF** you are going to be connecting from the client. There is no server side connection from your Netlify deploy (CDN) unless you plan to use netlify functions.

Comment: for once I disagree with @talves - see my answer below

Comment: My statement is true, but yes, I did assume he meant from the backend of his site, and did not consider a request to a proxy path.  Could also use a Netlify function also to talk to ngrok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netify [can proxy](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#proxying) to a dynamic backend, that is an intended use case.  The problem we'll have is using "localhost" - netlify needs a valid hostname to connect to.  So, if your ngrok is exposed (not firewalled) at some public IP, you can put that into your redirects configuration:

`/backend-stuff-in-this-path/* https://1.2.3.4/:splat 200!`

will send all requests to the path `/backend-stuff-in-this-path/ANYTHING` to the server at `1.2.3.4/ANYTHING`

This may not be incredibly useful since your machine will change IP addresses sometimes one presumes, but if you were using localhost anyway, you weren't planning to put it in production quite yet.  Note that redirects are deploy-specific, so you do need to redeploy to change the location if your IP changes.